# Raspberry Pi Monitor Compatibility

Tags: pi-3

I want to buy a raspberry pi 3 model b to serve as my test environment in programming. I have a monitor that is 21:9 and has a resolution of over 1920*1080. The specification of the monitor is in [this link](http://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-25UM58-P-ultrawide-monitor).
I would like to know the following:

1) Does the raspberry pi supports my monitor configuration?

2) If it does not support, does it support at least the 1920*1080 resolution?

3) The monitor has HDMI 2.0 ports. Does it has compatibility issues with HDMI 1.4?

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing the specs (upvote for providing the link) 
I would bet you a nickel that it will work just fine.

Hint:  If you plug the monitor into the Pi after the Pi has booted, it is normal to get strange resolutions.  The cure is to reboot.

In other words, hook the monitor up to the Pi before booting it up.

Answer (score 1):

Pi 3 module will automatically adjust to the best screen resolution. Don't worry.
And if anything goes wrong you can still customize ur desire resolution by editing the config.txt file in raspi-config